# Qt designer personalized forms in QField

Tags: qfield, qt-designer

Is it possible to use a form made in Qt Designer in the QField app?

The form works properly in QGIS but I don't see it when I try to open the project in QField?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only use autoforms or drag and drop.